# USB audio driver not getting built

Tags: audio, kernel-modules, yocto

I am having a problem with driver support for a USB sound card on an embedded system based on Raspberry Pi and Yocto Kirkstone.

The sound card is enumerated correctly by the USB subsystem, but doesn't appear as a sound card. The reason for that appears to be the fact that for some reason, snd-usb-audio doesn't exist in the system, even though I can see that it has been enabled as a module in kernel configuration. This conclusion is because the card works in another system which reports that it is using that driver for it. Other drivers  that are needed do exist in the system.

For the case it matters, on the system I have this problem with, the Raspberry Pi's analog audio output is not being listed by Linux either. The only audio output shown is the digital one that is part of the HDMI output.

`dmesg` for plugging in the sound card:

```
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: new full-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 3 but max is 2
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 3 but max is 2
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 3 but max is 2
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: config 1 has no interface number 2
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=262a, idProduct=10aa, bcdDevice= 0.01
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: Product: NuForce USB Audio
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] usb 1-1.3.4: Manufacturer: Nuforce Inc.
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] hid-generic 0003:262A:10AA.0004: No inputs registered, leaving
[Sun Apr  2 13:52:24 2023] hid-generic 0003:262A:10AA.0004: hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Nuforce Inc. NuForce USB Audio] on usb-20980000.usb-1.3.4/input0
```

`inxi -Ax` on a system where the sound card works (the card this question is about is number 3):

```
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD SBx00 Azalia vendor: ASRock driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.2
  Device-2: NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1
  Device-3: SAVITECH NuForce USB Audio type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 7-4:2
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-56-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

`grep snd /lib/modules/5.15.34/modules.builtin` on the system where the sound card is not working

```
kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko
kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko
kernel/sound/soc/snd-soc-core.ko
kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-hdmi-codec.ko
```

`grep SND_USB_AUDIO tmp/work/raspberrypi-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-raspberrypi/1_5.15.34+gitAUTOINC+e1b976ee4f_0086da6acd-r0/linux-raspberrypi-standard-build/.config`

```
CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO=m
CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO_USE_MEDIA_CONTROLLER=y
```

Comment: What is the output of `find /lib/modules -name 'snd-usb-audio*'`?

Comment: Nothing. All drivers there are related to net.

Comment: That suggests the kernel configuration file snippet you showed might not be from the kernel version that is actually being used on your embedded system. Does `/proc/config.gz` exist on the embedded system? If it does, what is the result of `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep SND_USB_AUDIO`?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist.

Comment: According to menuconfig, embedding the kernel configuration into kernel is enabled as a module and sharing it on /proc is enabled too (not as a module). This is weird.

Comment: grep IKCONFIG tmp/work/raspberrypi-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-raspberrypi/1_5.15.34+gitAUTOINC+e1b976ee4f_0086da6acd-r0/linux-raspberrypi-standard-build/.config
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=m
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y

Comment: The identifier `1_5.15.34+gitAUTOINC+e1b976ee4f_0086da6acd-r0` can be found verbatim in a [presentation](https://a4z.gitlab.io/talks/embed/bitbake101/#/_tasks_2). This suggests the kernel configuration file you're looking at might be just a generic example, not specific to your actual installation. Are there any `/boot/config-*` files present? What does `cat /proc/version` say?

Comment: No /boot/config-* files. cat /proc/version says
Linux version 5.15.34 (oe-user@oe-host) (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.38.20220708) #1 Tue Apr 19 19:21:26 UTC 2022.

Comment: As far as I know, that identifier is what Yocto uses as kernel version in this case. Given what that string is made of, I don't see a reason why it couldn't appear in other users' builds too.